# Alternative to Alldifferent constraint in excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007, solver

I am using excel 2007 to design a template for solving some optimization problems, but the only problem is that there is no "alldifferent" constraint in excel 2007 (the only version that is currently available), just wondering if it is possible to use any other alternatives for the alldifferent thing to substitute the following constraint:

$C$10:$C$14 = AllDifferent.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The all-different constraint is not very easy to express as linear equations. Assuming x(i) = 1..n (for i=1..n) we can write:

[image]

Note that this has n^2 binary variables. More information is [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/05/all-different-and-mixed-integer.html).